# Android app for switching the network from 2G to 3G

Tags: sip, voip

I am testing Voip call feature in my app. I need to test it in different networks. How it works when device switch in between networks (2G/3G/LTE/WiFi). Can any one help me out solving this issue.

Is there any app available in Play Store to test switching between networks scenario ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly you want to do? Do you have an App that currently doesn't support handover between networks and want help on getting this to work?

There should be numerous Apps in play store that support that, like hangouts, FB messenger, etc.

Comment: No, I need a app which will control the network in device and auto-switch in between networks